# How to convert "numeric string" to a date object using `as.Date()`?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, data-manipulation, coercion

I have a list of calendar dates in a data frame given in the format:

```
20000110 
20000117 
20000124
```

which standard for 2000-01-10, 2000-01-17, 2000-01-24, etc.

However, using

```
df %>% mutate(date= as.Date(df$data, format = "%Y%m%d") )
```

does not work. It springs an error asking me to supply an `origin`, which is an optional input for `as.Date()`. If I then supply the first date in my list as the origin, it gives me completely wrong dates:

```
df %>% mutate(date= as.Date(df$data, format = "%Y%m%d", origin="20000110") )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is of class `"numeric"`, so `as.Date.numeric` is dispatched which has `origin=` as second argument. So all you have to do is coerce `as.character` to dispatch `as.Date.character`, which has the desired `format=` argument.

```
transform(df, date=as.Date(as.character(date), '%Y%m%d'))
#         date
# 1 2000-01-10
# 2 2000-01-17
# 3 2000-01-24
```

Normally the `origin=` is January 1, 1970, the so-called Unix epoch, and a numeric `"date"` is the number of days since then (in `"POSIXt"` format seconds).

```
as.Date(as.numeric(Sys.Date()))
# Error in as.Date.numeric(as.numeric(Sys.Date())) : 
#   'origin' must be supplied

as.Date(as.numeric(Sys.Date()), origin='1970-01-01')
# [1] "2022-05-12"
```

Obviously this wouldn't make sense with your kind of numerics.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(20000110, 20000117, 20000124)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The trick is to use the `lubridate` library's `ymd()` function:

```
df %>% mutate(date= lubridate::ymd(df$data) )
```

This works perfectly!

Comment: Also:  `anytime::anydate(c(20000110, 20000117, 20000124))` which a) converts if needed and b) does not need a format hint (for 'sane' input formats such as this).  And for completeness, this works too:  `as.Date(as.character(c(20000110, 20000117, 20000124)), "%Y%m%d")`.